# PHP strip tags also removing \n

Tags: php, strip-tags

I'm using strip_tags in PHP and after it has processed the string, the string now also contains no \n's..

Is this standard with strip_tags?

Comment: Does it remove the real `\n`s or only the displayed newlines?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using? I just tested with PHP 5.3.x and it does not strip \n's for me.

Answer (score 9):

Well, is it so hard to test? :)

```
class StripTagsTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testStripTagsShouldNotRemoveLF() {
        $input = "Hello\n <b>World</b>\n";
        $actual = strip_tags($input);
        $expected = "Hello\n World\n";
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }

   public function testStripTagsRemovesBRTagByDefault() {
        $expected = "HelloWorld\n";
        $input = "Hello<br>World<br>\n";
        $actual = strip_tags($input);
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);

        $input = "Hello</br>World</br>\n";
        $actual = strip_tags($input);
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }

    public function testStripTagsCanPermitBRTags() {
        $expected = "Hello<br>World<br>\n";
        $actual = strip_tags($expected, '<br>');
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);

        $expected = "Hello</br>World</br>\n";
        $actual = strip_tags($expected, '<br>');
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }
}
```

This test will pass. The same result is while using single quotes. So, no, strip_tags doesn't remove \n.

EDIT:
Just as already other people here pointed out - strip_tags probably removes `<br>` tag in your case. Also, next time, if you provide some code, you will get your answer quicker.
Added two new tests :)

Answer (score 4):

Strip_tags should not remove \n but maybe it removes `<br>`.

Try adding a list of tags to permit:

```
strip_tags('Hello<br>World', '<br>');
```

this shold allow `<br>` tags to stay in the string.